# Potential energy density formula for waves on a string

Tags: forces, energy, waves, potential

For a string whose position is labelled by the x coordinate and the purely transverse displacement labelled by the y coordinate, then according to this [handout](https://users.physics.ox.ac.uk/%7Epalmerc/Wavesfiles/Energy_Handout.pdf), the potential energy density is
$$u_{p}(x)=\frac{1}{2}T(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x})^2$$where $T$ is the constant tension in the string. In the derivation for this formula, it was assumed that $$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}<<1,$$i.e. the string is close to equilibrium.

My question is, when is such a formula useful? For what waves in the real world can we use this formula? The condition $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}<<1$ seems to be quite a strong one such that the wave is nearly non-existent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a variation of the small angle approximation. It means the slope of the tangent line to the curve is much smaller than one. This means $\tan{x}\approx x$. That's good to one part in 10 if $|\frac{x}{\tan x}-1|<0.1$.

Examples of this use is really any system approximately in equilibrium. For example the actual equation of motion for a pendulum is $\frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2}+\frac{g}{l}\sin \theta=0$. While its non-linear, setting $\sin \theta \to \theta$ yields an easier equation to solve. That approximation for this problem is typically considered pretty good for initial displacements less than ten degrees.